# Any easy way to copy the logic behind how gitignore works?

Tags: python, gitignore

I need the same behavior as gitignore files, but for my own code that doesn't actually involve git. I'd like the behavior to match gitignore exactly, but looking at all the rules, it seems non-trivial.

I have files in a project. When running my Python script, it does things to those files. I'd like a .gitignore file that says to ignore some subset of files.

Is there some easy way to get that behavior, or do I need to write this from scratch?

Comment: I have files in a project. When running my Python script, it does things to those files. I'd like a .gitignore file that says to ignore some subset of files.

Comment: Are you comfortable depending on tools that shipped with git to do the parsing and interpretation for you?

Comment: You might be able to hack `git check-ignore` to work outside of an existing Git repo.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I need it to be pure python.

Comment: ...and it needs to be the *exact* same logic, not just something else that serves the same purpose adequately? Then you're going to need to reimplement the rules yourself, or find a 3rd-party library that's already done so (and requests to find 3rd-party libraries are explicitly off-topic on StackOverflow).

Comment: @user3715648 python can [call shell commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) and [read the output back](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). I use ffmpeg from python that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're working in a Git repository, `git check-ignore` does what you need:

```
$ echo "foo.pyc" | git check-ignore --stdin --no-index
foo.pyc
$ echo "foo.py" | git check-ignore --stdin --no-index
```

Otherwise, you will need to use a library that implements Git's pattern matching format. One such library is [`pathspec`](https://python-path-specification.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html). Read the documentation for a usage example.